# How do you move an input value into 2 decimal places?

Tags: angularjs

Basically what I want is that I have a condition that will let me know if I need to move my input value in 2 decimal places

I had used number and $filter api.

For example: 
I input $100 the system should display $1.00 if the condition is met.

Comment: The last 2 digits will be considered as a decimal places.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use `parseFloat` after dividing the value by 100

```js
var value = 100;
console.log(parseFloat(value/100).toFixed(2))
```